# vb.net POST request - object not found - do I need asynchronous requests?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, post, postback

Longshot and vague question here - I've successfully emulated sending multipart form data in POST requests to an in-house work system in order to create user accounts. Now when I try to edit and save the account changes I get an internal server error (500) with this response:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   TheSite.Pages.History.get_SomeHistoryFunction() in C:\Program Files (x86)\ServerSideFilePath\History.ascx.cs:999
   TheSite.Pages.History.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Program Files (x86)\ServerSideFilePath\History.ascx.cs:999
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +161 ' repeat this line 6 more times
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3810
```

I'm not sure what object reference the response is referring to, but after a little bit of digging and monitoring the traffic I see an "application/x-javascript" GET request is called after I get a response for the initial request.

I think I need to be sending ASYNC POST requests so a function call to this second request can be made after the initial response?

Here's the code I'm using to send POST requests, totally successfully except for this edit account page.

```
  Dim x As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(MULTIPART_SEND)

  oCON = WebRequest.Create("https://TheWorkSite/main/ViewEdit.aspx?ID=xyz)
  oCON.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
  oCON.Method = "POST"
  oCON.ContentLength = x.Length
  oCON.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & theBoundary

  dStr = oCON.GetRequestStream()
  dStr.Write(x, 0, x.Length)
  dStr.Close()

  oRES = oCON.GetResponse ' HERE IS WHERE THE WEB EXCEPTION ERROR IS THROWN
  oSTR = New StreamReader(oRES.GetResponseStream())
  TXT = oSTR.ReadToEnd()
```

Unfortunately I can't send in-house system details online or provide links to systems you wouldn't have access to anyway, but I noticed the function call name is within a script a near the top of the html on first viewing a page (where I parse viewstate etc) and after a save, my question is how do I include this function call or string with the initial request? I cannot see from the F12 viewer how it references it, it's not part of a header or the multipart form and I can't parse any instruction from the response because the response is a web exception error!

The format of the 2nd request is this and I think I need to connect this or call this after my first POST request, or include it WITH the first request.

```
/MySite/main/WebResource.axd?d=SomeABCDEFG=SomeNumbers
```

I've started looking at using .BeginGetResponse but the MSDN page went way over my head and I'm not even sure it's putting me in the right direction

Any ideas?! :/

Comment: Debug `get_SomeHistoryFunction()` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ServerSideFilePath\History.ascx.cs`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can debug something on the server side, using IE or Chrome F12 I can only find the WebResource.axd, I've realised I can see the <script> link to that 2nd GET request referring to the webresource but the `get_someHistoryFunction` is nowhere to be seen :/

Comment: Open the source code for the web site and debug it. If you don't have it, you can't do anything about it. The error happens on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I agree with that, what I don't understand is what could be missing/diffferent from my vb.net POST request to cause the error serverside, in comparison with the POST request sent via browser - the multipart form data is exactly the same, the headers all seem to match, the only difference I can conceive is that it's sent ASYNC instead of SYNC but would that even matter?